# Tensorflow Loops in Graph (Topological Sort Failed)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model that I've created in Tensorflow (using Keras).

In pseudo-code, without writing too much of the data-specific ops, it is roughly:

```
iter_count = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(input)

#scale iter_count between 1 and int_max


for i in tf.range(iter_count):

    inputvariation = tf.concat([input, i])
    
    box = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(inputvariation)

    #append to TensorArray

#stack and return TensorArray
```

However, this outputs an error that the model can't be sorted into topological order. Does this mean I can't run loops in my model?

Some errors:

E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:771] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_function_library_runtime.cc:941] Ignoring multi-device function optimization failure: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but it should be possible:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((5, ))
iter_count = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)

for i in tf.range(tf.shape(iter_count)[-1]):

    # if you want to get the actual output of the Dense layer **iter_count**
    # try i = itercount[:, i]
    inputvariation = tf.concat([inputs, tf.cast(tf.repeat(i, repeats=tf.shape(inputs)[0])[..., None], dtype=tf.float32)], axis=-1)
    box = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(inputvariation)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, box)

model(tf.random.normal((1, 5)))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. Basically, I wanted the first layer to predict how many bounding boxes are in an image, and the second to actually predict them (in the loop). I'll try running that code later, hopefully it works. Thanks for your help! Also, using tf.concat looks so much better than what I was doing with TensorArrays and .stack().

Comment: I have a question: Do I need to run model.compile()?

Comment: Of course :) if you plan to call `model.fit` afterwards

Comment: What about a custom training loop? (What I'm planning to do). I apologize for the comments, now I'm running into a new error,, no gradients provided for any variable

Comment: Short answer: with a custom training loop, you do not need to call `model.compile`. Kindly close this issue and ask a new question with more details.